# Fixed height in Container is not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, statelesswidget

Container height is set to fixed 40 but once I'm using that Widget in AppBar() it takes all the possible height. Here is the code for my custom widget which has Fixed height of Container,

```
class LPBorderButtonWithIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final GestureTapCallback onPressed;
  final String text;
  final String iconAsset;
  final Color textColor;

  LPBorderButtonWithIcon(
      {@required this.onPressed,
      @required this.text,
      @required this.textColor,
      @required this.iconAsset});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: onPressed,
        child: Container(
          height: 40,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              border: Border.all(color: Color(0XFFd8dce1))),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              WidthSizedBox(15),
              Image.asset(
                iconAsset,
                height: 14,
                width: 14,
              ),
              WidthSizedBox(5),
              Text(text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: textColor,
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontFamily: "GilroyMedium")),
              WidthSizedBox(15),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

and here I'm using `LPBorderButtonWithIcon()` in this screen,

```
class CreateRulesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreateRulesScreenState createState() => _CreateRulesScreenState();
}

class _CreateRulesScreenState extends State<CreateRulesScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 1,
        centerTitle: false,
        titleSpacing: 0.0,
        leading: BackButton(
          color: LPColor.primary,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        title: Text(
          "Create Rule",
          style: LPStyle.titleStyle,
        ),
        actions: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12, right: 16),
            child: LPBorderButtonWithIcon(
              onPressed: null,
              text: "Create",
              textColor: Color(0XFF508ff4),
              iconAsset: "images/ic_publish.png",
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

and below is the result where that custom container takes all the possible height. Please let me know how can I set fixed height to my custom widget.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Place your Container inside an Align, Aling will force the container to occupy only the space it needs.

```
Align(
   child: Container(
   height: 20,
   width: 30,
   color: Colors.white,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent widget takes the entire space available to draw the widget, Here `Container` is the parent widget, and it's taking whatever space is available, so to give height to the `Container`, that needed to be placed inside any widget which assigns **x,y position of widgets** to get it to draw.

```
Container(
    height: 40, // Its not going to apply height as it's parent widget
)
```

So to work out the above code you have to align Container to any other widget like Center, Align, etc.

For Eg:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    height: 600,
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Container(
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.yellow,
    ),
  ),
);
```

The above example child container will not draw yellow color in 200 height, it will take the entire 600 height space.

**Output:**

[image]

To Solve this we have assigned some widgets to the child `Container` so that it will get the x, y position to start drawing the child widget. Here `Center` widget is used.

Eg:

```
Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 600,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.yellow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Some Limitation:**

- A widget can decide its own size only within the constraints given to
  it by its parent. This means a widget usually can’t have any size it
  wants.
- A widget can’t know and doesn’t decide its own position in the
  screen, since it’s the widget’s parent who decides the position of
  the widget.
- Since the parent’s size and position, in its turn, also depends on
  its own parent, it’s impossible to precisely define the size and
  position of any widget without taking into consideration the tree as
  a whole.
- If a child wants a different size from its parent and the parent
  doesn’t have enough information to align it, then the child’s size
  might be ignored. Be specific when defining alignment.

**Reference link:** https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints